# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.RadioButton.setTypeface(android.graphics.Typeface)' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I am implementing radio group. When i try to run the app, i get this error  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.RadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(android.widget.RadioGroup$OnCheckedChangeListener)' on a null object reference.

```
radio_group_your_choice = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radio_group_your_choice);
        male_radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.male_radioButton);
        female_radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.female_radioButton);

        radio_group_your_choice.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId)
            {
                RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(checkedId);
                gender = radioButton.getText().toString();
            }
        });

<RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp">

                <RadioGroup
                    android:id="@+id/radio_group_your_choices"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/delivery_radioButton"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Pick Up"
                        android:textColor="@color/dark_grey"/>

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/pickup_radioButton"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                        android:text="Delivery"
                        android:textColor="@color/dark_grey"/>


                </RadioGroup>

            </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this radio group is null:

```
radio_group_your_choice
```

try to ask before `setOnCheckedChangeListener`

```
if (radio_group_your_choice!= null)
```

to avoid this exeption.

Comment: Still the same error java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.RadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(android.widget.RadioGroup$OnCheckedChangeListener)' on a null object reference

Comment: radioGroup, radioButtons are null.

Comment: try to check why is it null, do you have it in your screen, or it is in another layout? it seems this radiobutton didn't create

Comment: yes but did you load in OnCreate this layout or another one? how dose this layout call? and waht did you put in setContentView?

Comment: https://paste.ofcode.org/txjFQ3w9DRCqmpyjRamc7X Here i have added the code. I have set activity_search

Comment: setContentView(R.layout.activity_search); This is what has been set before. But I am working on fragment_main.xml